# How to add ssh daemon to emergency mode with systemd

Tags: ssh, systemd, gentoo

I have a headless server that I cannot access. How do I make ssh start in emergency mode so I can get into it if something goes wrong?

Comment: You should really consider setting up KVM access, because lots of things can go wrong even before the system has a chance to start ssh (firmware, bootloader, initramfs, root fs, base system, etc.). If it's a server, it likely has some sort of a BMC (IPMI, ILO) with at least serial-console-over-IP if not KVM-over-IP.